# Web Worker instances fail to respond (?) after period of time

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm using https://github.com/substack/webworkify like so:

```
let outputWorker = work(require('./key-output-worker'))
this.keyOutputWorkers.push(outputWorker)
outputWorker.addEventListener('message', this.onKeyOutputWorkerMessage)
outputWorker.postMessage({action: 'makeKeyOutput', visible})
```

And my worker code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'

import Key from './key.jsx';

const makeKeyOutput = (model) => {
  // returns new React element
}

module.exports = function(self) {

  const onMessage = (event) => {
    if (event.data.action == 'makeKeyOutput') {
      let output = event.data.visible.map(v => ReactDOMServer.renderToString(makeKeyOutput(v))).join('')
      if (output) {
        self.postMessage(output)
      }
      self.removeEventListener('message', onMessage)
      self.close()
    }
  }

  self.addEventListener('message', onMessage)
}
```

I'm invoking the instantiation code every ~500ms or so. All works well, until suddenly I see this in the Network tab in Chrome:

[image]

If I add an `outputWorker.onerror` callback, I just get an Error event raised, but no details to really debug.

What is my best approach for debugging here? Kinda stuck!

Comment: did you try/catch the code inside the worker and log it ?

Comment: I did! Nothing fell through to the `catch` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯